# How can I change ant design progress bar color according to value?

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro

I want to give 'yellow' color until 50%, after 50% it will display 'green'.

It is not like *strokeColor* feature. I want to see yellow or green. Not together.

Is it possible to handle it (preferred without css)?

```
import { Progress } from 'antd';
```

```
<Progress 
  percent={this.state.progress}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `strokeColor` props:

```js
<Progress 
  percent={this.state.progress}
  strokeColor={this.state.progress < 50 ? "yellow" : "green"}
/>
```

check it there: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-ant-design-demo-icli2

Answer (score 0):

use strokeColor

<Progress type="circle" percent={progressbar} strokeColor={'green'} />